# C Array Looping Error

Tags: c, arrays, string, gets

I'm supposed to write a simple C program to read in an integer and loop n times to work on the string, but the first loop automatically passes an empty string if I use the scanf integer, but if I use a constant number the loop works right. Somebody please explain to me what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 80

int main(){
    char sentence[MAX];
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){//it loops with empty string automatically if I replace 3 with n
        gets(sentence);
        printf("%s\n", sentence);
    }
}
```

Comment: scanf does not consume the newline after the integer

Comment: You could start by never using `gets` - see [elsewhere on this site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) for why

Comment: [Why the `gets()` function is always dangerous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: I switched to fgets, but I don't know how to get rid of the newline character after scanning the integer

Comment: @JSamson, Just add `getchar();` after the `scanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    #define MAX 80
    void main()
    {
    char sentence[MAX];
    int n,i;
    clrscr();
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf(" %99[^\n]",sentence);
    printf("\n%s\n",sentence);
    getch();

    }
```